# Error in filtering by child object in Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My code structure looks like the following.

Article:

```
@Entity
public class NewsArticle{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    [Other class properties such as title, publisher, publishedDate, etc.]        

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    private Set<UserReadNewsArticle> userReadNewsArticles = new HashSet<>();

    [Getters and Setters]
}
```

Article read by User:

```
@Entity
public class UserReadNewsArticle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long readAccountId;    
    private Long readArticleId;           

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private NewsArticle article;

    [Getters and Setters]


}
```

Account:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    [Other class properties]

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private Set<UserReadNewsArticle> userReadNewsArticles = new HashSet<>();

    [Getters and Setters]
}
```

I want to have a query method in my NewsArticleRepository to get all the Read News Articles for a user.

```
public interface NewsArticleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<NewsArticle, Long>{

    Collection<NewsArticle> findByUserReadNewsArticlesReadAccountId(Long readAccountId);

}
```

This method works great. But how can I write a Spring Data JPA Query/Method to get the "Unread News Articles for a user". What I have tried is the following.

```
Collection<NewsArticle> findByUserReadNewsArticlesReadAccountIdNot(Long readAccountId);
```

This one does return a list of articles which have been read by other users. But my **requirement is to get all the unread news articles**. I have gone through [Spring Data JPA Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) but failed to come up with an easier soultion. How can I overcome this issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [jpa docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) says you can use `not in` so it seems  `Collection<NewsArticle> findNotInUserReadNewsArticlesByReadAccountId(Long readAccountId);` would work.

Comment: @fiskra this won't work as in, I want to do the selection from **NewsArticleRepository**, not UserReadNewsArticlesRepository. And I have already played around with **NotIn**, but that has not been able to solve it yet

Comment: Apart from your problem.. I assume you can delete both fields `readAccountId` and `readArticleId` because you already bound the entities.

Comment: @KLHauser that's true. I keep those values as I need 'em for a few different tasks.

Comment: If you found the solution, please add as the answer. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your result by using a JPQL query with also a subquery:

```
public interface NewsArticleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<NewsArticle, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT n FROM NewsArticle n WHERE n NOT IN "
            + "(SELECT ur.article FROM UserReadNewsArticle ur JOIN ur.account a WHERE a.id = :readAccountId)")
    Collection<NewsArticle> findByUserReadNewsArticlesReadAccountIdNotIn(@Param("readAccountId") Long readAccountId);

}
```

http://localhost:8080/newsArticles/search/findByUserReadNewsArticlesReadAccountIdNotIn?readAccountId=1

So first get the read articels from the current user and then exlude them from the whole article list.

I don't think that spring data is able to get you the same, since a subquery is definitetly needed. If I'm wrong, somebody can correct me.

Comment: I added some more information. Maybe this helps. If not, what is happening?

Comment: It actually does work. Amazing. I must have made a mistake the previous time I tried it. Thank you so much.