# How can I make a sort with filtering using JPA Criteria API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I have entities mapping db described by the following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "myitem")
public class MyItem {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String type;
}

@Entity(name = "mycontainer")
public class MyContainer {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @ManyToOne
   private MyItem item;
   ...
}

@Entity(name = "mytable")
public class MyTable {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @OneToMany
   private Set<MyContainer> containers;
   ...
}
```

I am using JPA Criteria API to filter and sort my data. Sort and filter parameters change dynamically and to get results from db I use Spring Data JPA `Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable)` ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Example-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-)). 
It works good for basic sorting, but I have a problem when I want to sort `MyTable` by `MyItem.id` of certain type. Example: each container has 2 items of different types and I want to sort table by items IDs of only one type ignoring second one values.
Is it even possible to accomplish such sorting with Spring Data JPA?

Edit: I need a dynamic approach here because it is important that my sorting can be done by various fields selected by user.

Comment: Look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487455/error-in-filtering-by-child-object-in-spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Hi. I am looking for some dynamic sorting solution because in my system sorting should be done by a field specified by user. Defining more methods in the repository won't help me.

Answer (score 1):

After you've joined the entities, you can use the `orderBy` method of the `CriteriaQuery` interface and the `asc` or `desc` methods of the `CriteriaBuilder` interface to define an ORDER BY clause.

```
cq.orderBy(cb.asc(item.get(MyItem_.id)));
```

Here's a complete example that joins `MyTable` with `MyContainer` with `MyItem` and selects `MyTable` entities ordered by the `id` of `MyItem`

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyTable> cq = cb.createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> root = cq.from(MyTable.class);
SetJoin<MyTable, MyContainer> containers = root.join(MyTable_.containers);
Join<MyContainer, MyItem> item = containers.join(MyContainer_.item);

cq.orderBy(cb.asc(item.get(MyItem_.id)));

TypedQuery<MyTable> query = em.createQuery(cq);
List<MyTable> tables = query.getResultList();

for (MyTable t : tables) {
    log.info(t);
}

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

All classes that end with an `_` are [JPA metamodel](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/static-metamodel/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer) classes. Each of them describes the entity with the same name without the `_`.